# Complexity of counting colorings of co-bipartite graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

A graph is co-bipartite if it is the complement of bipartite graph.

What is the complexity of counting colorings of co-bipartite graphs?

Unlike split graphs, the chromatic polynomial isn't of particularly
simple form. Co-bipartite graphs are also known as (2,0)-colorable.